# Using username for password in Django

Tags: django

When registering a user, the password should be the same as the username, and the user should change the password later

> view :

```
 @login_required
def member_create(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
      form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         form.save()
         messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'ok')
        return redirect("member_index")
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.warning, 'eror')
        return redirect("member_index")
  else:
     form = CreateUserForm()

  context = {
      'form': form
    }
   return render(request, 'member/register.html', context)
```

> forms :

```
     class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = [
        'username',
        'codemeli',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
    ]
```

> models :

```
     class Profile(AbstractUser):
codemeli = models.CharField(
    max_length=10, verbose_name='کد ملی', unique=True)
fname_en = models.CharField(
    max_length=150, verbose_name='نام لاتین', null=True, blank=True)
lname_en = models.CharField(
    max_length=150, verbose_name='نام خانوادگی لاتین', null=True, blank=True)


def save(self):
    self.password=self.username
    super().save()
```

what can i do ؟؟؟؟

Comment: Share your `CreateUserForm` form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> view :

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
if request.method == "POST":
    form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
    username = request.POST['username']
    first_name = request.POST['first_name']
    last_name = request.POST['last_name']
    register = Profile( username=username, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name,)
        register.password = make_password(username)
        register.codemeli = username
        register.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

use the function for password

```
user.set_password(username)
```

Answer (score 0):

> view :

```
 from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password


`if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        username = request.POST['username']
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        

        register = Profile(
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            )
        
        register.password = make_password(username)
        register.codemeli = username
        register.save()
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'ثبت با موفقیت انجام شد')
        return redirect("member_index")
    else:
        form = CreateUserForm()`
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pre_save signal or post_save signal. for instance,

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Profile)
def update_password(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.password = instance.username
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this view function

```
 @login_required
def member_create(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
      form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         user=form.save(commit=False)
         user.password=user.username
         user.save()
         messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'ok')
        return redirect("member_index")
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.warning, 'eror')
        return redirect("member_index")
  else:
     form = CreateUserForm()

  context = {
      'form': form
    }
   return render(request, 'member/register.html', context)
```